# Angular Async Router Navigation Not Working

Tags: angular, rest, async-await

After I send a request to my REST API and the login is success I want to navigate to another page. 
I found out that I need to use async and await for this.

login.component.ts:

```
onLoginSubmit() {
this.submitted = true;
if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
  return;
}

this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password).then(async (result: AuthModel) => {
  this.cookieService.set('token', result.token);
  console.log(result.token, result.succes);
  await this.router.navigateByUrl['dashboard'];

},(error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.router.navigateByUrl['/dashboard'];
  });
}
```

auth.service.ts:

```
async login(username: string, password: string): Promise<AuthReturnModel> {
const loginModel: LoginModel = new LoginModel();
loginModel.username = username;
loginModel.password = password;

let authReturnModel: AuthReturnModel;

await this.httpClient.post<AuthReturnModel>(API_URL +"/users/login", loginModel)
.pipe(
  map((data: AuthReturnModel) => authReturnModel = data)
).pipe(
  catchError(error => of(`Bad Promise: ${error}`))
).toPromise();
return authReturnModel;
}
```

The page 'dashboard' will not be loaded?
thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe you have a guard in your application. You didn't show it. It could prevent the dashboard from loading. Please also show the guard.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I don't use guard its all custom made authorization

Comment: A guard is also custom?! Are you aware that without a guard any user can route to dashboard when entered as url directly?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missing the `/` in your navigateByUrl call

`this.router.navigateByUrl['/dashboard'];`

Additional i don't think you need the await before navigateByUrl, you are already inside your async call if using then.

[Here](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-tutorial-reactive-forms/) you can find a fully working example / tutorial for using login in angular. 
The used login call in the example is:

```
  login(){
    console.log(this.loginForm.value);
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if(this.loginForm.invalid){
      return;
    }
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the auth service, you're returning authReturnModel but in the component, you are expecting a promise. (you have used `then` to capture the result.).

I think since you are using the promise you can use this without using the async wait,

```
login(username: string, password: string): Promise<AuthReturnModel> {
  const loginModel: LoginModel = new LoginModel();
  loginModel.username = username;
  loginModel.password = password;

  let authReturnModel: AuthReturnModel;

  return this.httpClient.post<AuthReturnModel>(API_URL +"/users/login", loginModel)
   .pipe(
      map((data: AuthReturnModel) => authReturnModel = data),
      catchError(error => of(`Bad Promise: ${error}`))
    ).toPromise(); 
}
```

component.

```
this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password).then((result: AuthModel) => {
  this.cookieService.set('token', result.token);
  console.log(result.token, result.succes);
  this.router.navigateByUrl['dashboard'];

},(error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this.router.navigateByUrl['/dashboard'];
  });
}
```

Comment: it says that the .then() is needed ?

Comment: then is used to get the result from the promise. since you've used the `toPromise` option, you have to use the `then`

Comment: I'm using the .then() method in my component? or do you mean in the service file?

Comment: in the component. i'm suggesting drop the async-await.